# Locking the Aspect Ratio of an NSDocument's window

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit

I have a document based application and I am trying to lock the aspect ratio of the document's window. The content of the document is a custom view which I can easily set an aspect ratio. However, when I resize the window, there is a black background that fills the space between the view and the window. I have tried overriding the aspectRatio of the window in my documents class however that does not seem to do the trick.

```
- (NSSize)aspectRatio {
    return NSMakeSize(600,480);
}
```

I also tried setting the windows aspect ratio once the nib is loaded. This did the trick when my app was not document based.

```
[window setAspectRatio:window.frame.size];
```

I have one more kicker... Assuming that I can lock in the window's aspect ratio, I want to override that when the user clicks the Zoom button to put the app at full screen. Then and only then will I want to fill the space between the view and the window.

I have been researching for quite sometime and just cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> there is a black background that fills the space between the view and the window

Can’t you just set the window background to a different colour?

> I have tried overriding the aspectRatio of the window in my documents class

In your subclass of `NSDocument`? If overriding `-aspectRatio` works, it should be in a subclass of `NSWindow`. However, you should use `-setAspectRatio:`.

> I also tried setting the windows aspect ratio once the nib is loaded. This did the trick when my app was not document based.

This works regardless of the window belonging to a document- or non-document-based application.

> I want to override that when the user clicks the Zoom button to put the app at full screen

You can have a window delegate that implements `–windowShouldZoom:toFrame:`, which is part of the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol.

---

Since the OP is developing a document-based application with no custom subclass of `NSWindow` or `NSWindowController`, implementing:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    [[aController window] setAspectRatio:(NSSize){600,400}];
}
```

in the `NSDocument` subclass is the only change needed to set the aspect ratio on a project based upon the document-based application template in Xcode.

In general, I’d advise against having a `NSDocument` subclass that is responsible for windows as well as documents. In my opinion, a better design is to have the `NSDocument` subclass deal with documents only, and create a subclass of `NSWindowController` that deals with windows only — think [functional cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) or the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: @Bavarious: I don't believe you're correct that the window size must be an integral multiple. I've done `[window setAspectRatio:[window frame].size];` (just double-checked now) and had no such issue with resizing.

Comment: @Josh True; the documentation can be a tad misleading.

Comment: Yes. My class is a subclass of NSDocument. I can't subclass to NSWindow or else I would break all kinds of other things that NSDocument provides me. I did try to use `-setAspectRatio:` however, it does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: Can my class be a subclass of both NSDocument and NSWindow?

Comment: @Joe How do you obtain the `NSWindow *` reference to the document window? And no, a class has at most one (direct) superclass.

Comment: @Joe Also, in my experience it’s better to use window controllers and keep `NSDocument` subclasses dealing with model data and behaviour only. Otherwise, as your application grows in complexity, you end up having a single class responsible for both model and view data/behaviour.

Comment: I create a window object as apart of my class. `NSWindow *window;`. Then I associated that window object with actual window in Interface Builder. As apart of my NSDocument class, I do have a window controller. I explored that path but was not able to find a way to tell the window controller to set the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Joe If you have a window controller, then `[[self window] setAspectRatio:…]` inside the `-windowDidLoad` method in your window controller.

Comment: I guess that I should clarify that NSDocument seems to create its own Window Controller. Correct me if I am wrong but if I wanted to use `-windowDidLoad` than I would need to create my own subclass of NSWindowController and have my document load it. Seems like a lot of work for something so simple. Would sure be nice if there was a ratio configuration inside Interface Builder.

Comment: I also tried adding `[[aController window] setAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(600.0, 480.0)];` into `- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController` but that did not seem to work either.

Comment: @Joe It should’ve worked. Have you set the `window` outlet in the nib file?

Comment: @Joe Also, have you overridden `-windowNibName`?

Comment: @Joe I guess at this point you should edit your question and paste the contents of your `NSDocument` class.